# Add a column of unique items to a table

Tags: jquery, html

Imagine that I have a table, like so:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
  <tr><td>D</td><td>E</td></tr>
  <tr><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
</table>
```

Rendered, the table appears like so:

```
A B
D E
G H
```

I wish to add a new column to this table, so that it appears as:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

I know I can use jQuery to add a new column like so:

```
$('table tr').append('<td>NEW</td>');
```

Which results in:

```
A B NEW
D E NEW
G H NEW
```

I wonder if there is a way to append a unique item to the end of each row. The following does not do this, but something similar would be nice:

```
$('table tr').append('<td>C</td>','<td>F</td>','<td>I</td>');
```

Comment: It's hilarious how the simple jQuery questions get pounced on and answered simultaneously by at least a few people. Low hanging fruit and all that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) that takes an callback as its argument and then using an array return the item to be returned

```
var array = ['<td>C</td>', '<td>F</td>', '<td>I</td>'];
$('table tr').append(function (i) {
    return array[i];
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gntL2636/)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is keep your data in an array. like

```
tdArray=["<td>C</td>", '<td>F</td>', '<td>I</td>'];
var i = 0;
```

and do

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    $(this).append(tdArray[i]);
    i++
}
```

Comment: The first parameter in the callback for `each()` is an index, so you don't need to keep your own counter: `$('table tr').each(function (i) { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append) can take a function which gets an index parameter, as well as each matched element in the jQuery set, so you can use that to do conditional logic for each row.

e.g. a simple example:

```
$('table tr').append(function (i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0: return '<td>C</td>';
        case 1: return '<td>F</td>';
        case 2: return '<td>F</td>';
    }
});
```

Of course, you can add whatever smarts you need.